# Python: How can I sort file line by line in lexicographic order and write result to file?

Tags: python, sorting

I'm a beginner in Python and having trouble understanding this question. Can someone check to see if my code reflects the instructions / how to fix it? Thank you!

Question: Write a function sortFile(src, dst) that sorts file with name src line by line in lexicographic order and writes the result to file with name dst without modifying src. Hint: If f is a file object, list(f) reads the whole file as a list of lines. Use the sort method of lists for sorting and the join method of strings for concatenating a list of strings. For example sorting text.txt would result in a file with:

> An apple is red.
>
> A Banana is blue.
>
> Fruits are great.

text.txt file:

An apple is red.

A Banana is blue.

Fruits are great.

My code:

```
def sortFile(src, dst):
    x, y = open(src, 'r'), open(dst, 'w')
    b = x.readlines()
    x.close()
    b.sort()
    for i in b:
        print((str(i).strip()), file=y)
    y.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use file.write(string) to write to the ouput file:

```
def sortFile(src, dst):
    x, y = open(src, 'r'), open(dst, 'w')
    b = x.readlines()
    x.close()
    b.sort()
    for i in b:
        y.write(i.strip() + "\n")
    y.close()
```

I tested this and it should produce the correct result.

Comment: `.write` and `print` should not produce different output in this case.  Why do you think that would make a difference?

Comment: @spookyblack You just call sortFile("testFile.txt", "output.txt") for example. The second parameter just creates a file of that name to write ouput to, although note that if that file already exists it will be overwritten.

Comment: Also @SethMMorton I don't think that it would make a difference, write() is just better code practice imho, because it is clearer what you're doing.

Comment: I strongly disagree, because calling `str` on non string arguments to `.write` can make intent unclear.